# SharedPreferences aren't resetting using remove(); or clear();

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to reset my SharedPreferences, but neither clear(), nor remove() work.

```
            SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
            editor = preferences.edit();

            for (int t = 0; t < homeTiles.size(); t++) {

                editor.remove(homeTiles.get(t).getmFunction() + "_tile_pos");   //this isnt running
                editor.remove(homeTiles.get(t).getmFunction() + "_tile_vis");   //this is getting ecexuted

            }

            editor.apply();
```

I also checked the preference file and it did'nt change.

Comment: Can you try `commit()` along with `apply` in both `remove()` and `clear`

Comment: If you are removing information for all the tiles you stored into the shared preferences, I'd suggest to use a dedicated shared preferences file for them `getSharedPreferences(
       "Home tiles", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)` and just clear it `editor.clear().apply()` instead of using the loop.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
for (int t = 0; t < homeTiles.size(); t++) {
    editor.remove(homeTiles.get(t).getmFunction() + "_tile_pos").remove();   //this isnt running
    editor.remove(homeTiles.get(t).getmFunction() + "_tile_vis").remove();   //this is getting ecexuted
}
```